# Is it possible to run a VBA function whenever Outlook starts up?

Tags: vba, outlook, startup

I would like to have a VBA function run as soon as Outlook starts up. Is this possible and if so, what do I need to do? My searches on Google have failed me.

I don't mind that the security alert will pop up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `Application_Startup` event in `ThisOutlookSession`:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    MsgBox "Foo"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `ThisOutlookSession` - the other answers I'd found did not provide the context where `Application_Startup` needed to be.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, then call your macro that you want to start up.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Application_Startup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155701%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_ch11olevents_topic2) event?