# Macro not working after outlook restart

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a code which checks subject and email for a specific string and notifies users with YES/NO option.

When I restart outlook, I need to manually run MACRO to make it work.

I tried below code but I still need to run it manually.

```
Public WithEvents PasswordCheck As Outlook.Application
Public Sub Initialize_handler()
   Set PasswordCheck = Outlook.Application
End Sub

Private Sub PasswordCheck_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim strBody As String
  Dim strSubject As String
  strSubject = Item.Subject
  strBody = Item.Body
UCasePasswd = UCase("Test_123")
prompt = "Are you sure you want to send this email? It contains  Password: "
If InStr(1, UCase(strSubject), UCasePasswd) > 0 Or _
InStr(1, UCase(strBody), UCasePasswd) > 0 Then
If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Check for Subject") = vbNo Then
Cancel = True
End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PasswordCheck_Startup()
Initialize_handler
End Sub
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565256/7889129

Comment: I already checked that. Problem is code is not working. When I restart outlook, macro is not executed unless I go an re-run it. I need help with how do we call macro in Startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I automatically run a macro when an email is sent in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806335/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-macro-when-an-email-is-sent-in-outlook)

Comment: Nope. Link do not explain how to resolve the problem. I am looking for a solution using which once I place my code in outlook it should work whenever I restart my outlook.

Comment: Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002026/outlook-events-not-firing which specifically states how to trigger events when using the convoluted way found in documentation.

Comment: I incorporated best answer from that link already. Once I restart outlook, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The `Application_Startup()` code is in `ThisOutlookSession` isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Application_startup is replaced by PasswordCheck_Startup(). It doesnt work when I restart outlook. Entire code is present in ThisOutlookSession 

Private Sub PasswordCheck_Startup()
Initialize_handler
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your procedure name

```
Private Sub PasswordCheck_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
```

should be

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
```

and be stored in the `ThisOutlookSession` module.

You should also place `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare `UCasePasswd` and `prompt` as string variables.

After testing this code worked without need to call it with the `Application_Startup()` routine as it's a built in event.

Also, I don't think you can re-reference `Application_Startup` as `PasswordCheck_Startup` the same way I've never seen `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` changed to anything else in Excel.

**Edit:**
This code in `ThisOutlookSession` worked perfectly - it's the only code in the module.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim UCasePasswd As String
    Dim prompt As String

    strSubject = Item.Subject
    strBody = Item.Body
    UCasePasswd = "TEST_123" 'Rather than use UCASE, just write it in upper case.
    prompt = "Are you sure you want to send this email? It contains Password: "
    If InStr(UCase(strSubject), UCasePasswd) > 0 Or InStr(UCase(strBody), UCasePasswd) > 0 Then
        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Check for Subject") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. It works as expected. Appreciate your time and explanation.

Comment: The OP's code, promoted in the documentation, works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/application-itemsend-event-outlook  To run at startup put Initialize Handler in Application_Startup.

Comment: @niton I'll have a look and add as an edit if applicable when I'm next on my PC.

Comment: @niton I see what you mean. `PasswordCheck_ItemSend` will work. The OP just needs to change `PasswordCheck_Startup()` to `Application_Startup()` and the original code will work.